# Show all rows with group_by - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter. Below is my code

```
public function get_content(){
   $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status', "Active");
        $this->db->group_by('MONTH(content_publish_date)');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}
```

I want to extract the rows by month & result will be shown month wise..
But as per the above query i am getting only one row of each month.. i need all the rows to show results monthwise.. Please help.

[image: Result needed]

Comment: If you have more than one row for a month you want one row?

Comment: there will be multiple rows in the table with different months

Comment: In that case you should do `order_by` see the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all your where clause has extra parenthesis in statement

```
$this->db->where('status'), "Active");
```

change it like this

```
$this->db->where('status', "Active");
```

secondly add order by instead of group by , but order by should be on date

```
$this->db->order_by('DATE(content_publish_date)', 'DESC');
```

thirdly get current record's month in select as

```
$this->db->select('*,MONTH(content_publish_date) as content_publish_month');
```

mean your final query will be

```
    $this->db->select('*,MONTH(content_publish_date) as content_publish_month');
    $this->db->from('content_table');
    $this->db->where('status', "Active");
    $this->db->order_by('DATE(content_publish_date)', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

then in view you will have to add a variable which will check if month is same as previous record's month then just show record else show month header too e.g:

```
$lastMonth = 0;
foreach($result as $oneRec)
{
    if(($lastMonth == 0) || ($lastMonth != $oneRec['content_publish_month'])
    {
        //show header
        echo date('F Y', strtotime($row['content_publish_date']));
        //check if its first record or not
        if($lastMonth != 0)
        {
            echo '</table>';
        }
        //then add table start tag
        echo = '<table><tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Publication</th>
    </tr>';
    }
    //show record here
    echo = '<tr>
        <td>'.$oneRec['content_publish_date'].'</td>
        <td>'.$oneRec['title'].'</td>
        <td>'.$oneRec['publication'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    //then set current record's month as last month as
    $lastMonth = $oneRec['content_publish_month'];
}
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: you tried it or not? if tried can u send me result snapshot?

Comment: I was looking for something like this. This saved a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`

Do like this:

```
public function get_content(){
   $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status', "Active");
        $this->db->order_by('MONTH(content_publish_date)', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Write this code in your view file:

```
$month = "";  
foreach($paaed_arr AS $row){        

  $dbmonth = date('m', strtotime($row['content_publish_date']);

  if($month != $dbmonth){

      echo date('F Y', strtotime($row['content_publish_date']));
      $month = $dbmonth;
      }
              // Put your code here to display records of this month ....
}
```

[GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) is used for grouping the same data, while [ORDER BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) is used for sorting of data

Let me know more help!

Comment: but it will not be easy for formatting.. i want to show each month with its rows seperately..

Comment: Ok. Give me some documentary / graphical view how you need to show records, so I can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but Its not working its not easy to format & extract data by month.

Comment: Its not grouping the data which have same month.

Answer (score 2):

to achieve this you should order the date colmn.. try this ...

```
public function get_content(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status'), "Active");
        $this->db->order_by("MONTH(content_publish_date)", "asc"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}
```